# How to change text color in ripple effect

Tags: flutter, button

Is it possible to change the color of the text that's under the splash color during ripple effect on material button in Flutter ?
Im putting a splash color that is the same color as the texte and i want the text to turn white to become visible.
[Splash hides text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrkJ9.gif)

I want something like this to happen
[Text turn to white under splash color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjvDp.png)

Comment: Are you creating a custom animation for the ripple effect?

Comment: No. Im using the splachColor property of button widget

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GestureDetector`and change text color in `onLongPress` or `onLongPressStart` or something else.

Comment: I want the text color to change only when splash color pass over it. The texte color shouldn't change all at once